# Recursive Fibonacci Assembly MIPS code

Tags: assembly, recursion, mips, fibonacci

I have created a code generator for my coursework in a module compilers. It generates code in MIPS assembly code and seems to be working ok (ive tested very simple programs and expressions). 
I tested the recursive Fibonacci program and it currently loops forever. The base cases, 0 and 1, work ok. But when I try fib(2) or more it keeps looping.
Not sure what the problem is, can anyone help me find it?

Here is the code:

```
main: 
move $fp $sp 
sw $ra 0($sp)
addiu $sp $sp -4 
sw $fp 0($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp -4 
li $a0 2 #testing comment
sw $a0 0($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp -4 
jal fib_entry 
lw $ra 4($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp 8 
lw $fp 0($sp) 
li $v0, 10 
syscall 
fib_entry: 
move $fp $sp 
sw $ra 0($sp)
addiu $sp $sp -4 
lw $a0 4($fp) 
sw $a0 0($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp -4 
li $a0 0 
lw $t1 4($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp 4 
beq $a0 $t1 thenBranch1
elseBranch1: 
lw $a0 4($fp) 
sw $a0 0($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp -4 
li $a0 1 
lw $t1 4($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp 4 
beq $a0 $t1 thenBranch2
elseBranch2: 
sw $fp 0($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp -4 
lw $a0 4($fp) 
sw $a0 0($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp -4 
li $a0 1 
lw $t1 4($sp) 
sub $a0 $t1 $a0 
addiu $sp $sp 4 
sw $a0 0($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp -4 
jal fib_entry 
sw $a0 0($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp -4 
sw $fp 0($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp -4 
lw $a0 4($fp) 
sw $a0 0($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp -4 
li $a0 2 
lw $t1 4($sp) 
sub $a0 $t1 $a0 
addiu $sp $sp 4 
sw $a0 0($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp -4 
jal fib_entry 
lw $t1 4($sp) 
add $a0 $a0 $t1 
addiu $sp $sp 4 
b endIf2 
thenBranch2: 
li $a0 1 
endIf2: 
b endIf1 
thenBranch1: 
li $a0 0 
endIf1: 
lw $ra 4($sp) 
addiu $sp $sp 12 
lw $fp 0($sp) 
jr $ra
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various problems with that code.

1. you should be decrementing `$sp` **before** you write to `($sp)` (although this is only by convention)
2. you should be saving `$fp` **before** you modify it (this is by common sense ;))
3. MIPS typically uses registers to pass arguments (but you can of
   course make up your own convention)
4. your stack handling is horribly overcomplicated, and at least in `main` it's unbalanced
5. it's recommended to return from `main` and not use `exit` syscall

You should of course be able to write and debug asm code before you try to generate some.

Given an input structured something like this C implementation:

```
unsigned fib_entry(unsigned n) {
    unsigned ret;
    unsigned n1;
    unsigned f1;
    unsigned n2;
    unsigned f2;

    if (n <= 1) goto fib_small;

    n1 = n - 1;
    f1 = fib_entry(n1);
    n2 = n - 2;
    f2 = fib_entry(n2);
    ret = f1 + f2;
    goto fib_done;

fib_small:
    ret = n;

fib_done:
    return ret;
}
```

I would expect a not-too-clever compiler to produce code like this:

```
fib_entry:
    addiu $sp $sp -28   # we need room for $ra, n, ret, n1, n2, f1, f2
    sw $ra, 24($sp)     # store $ra since not leaf function
    sw $a0, 20($sp)     # store n

    lw $t0, 20($sp)     # load n
    ble $t0 1 fib_small

    lw $t0, 20($sp)     # load n
    addi $t0 $t0 -1     # n - 1
    sw $t0, 12($sp)     # store as n1

    lw $a0, 12($sp)     # pass n1 as argument
    jal fib_entry
    sw $v0 4($sp)       # store into f1

    lw $t0, 20($sp)     # load n
    addi $t0 $t0 -2     # n - 2
    sw $t0, 8($sp)      # store as n2

    lw $a0, 8($sp)      # pass n2 as argument
    jal fib_entry
    sw $v0 ($sp)        # store into f2

    lw $t0 4($sp)       # f1
    lw $t1 ($sp)        # f2
    addu $t0 $t0 $t1    # f1 + f2
    sw $t0 16($sp)      # store into ret

    b fib_done

fib_small:
    lw $t0, 20($sp)     # load n
    sw $t0 16($sp)      # store into ret

fib_done:
    lw $v0 16($sp)      # load return value
    lw $ra 24($sp)      # restore $ra
    addiu $sp $sp 28    # restore stack
    jr $ra              # return
```

Note I have deliberately left it unoptimized. This kind of code should be simple enough to generate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I will fix up my code with the help of your points ^^